# Move files to folders with same name in Java

Tags: java, file-handling, stringindexoutofbounds

I have files and folders with same name(without characters of extensions). I try to move each files to the right folders with following code.

```
private static void moveFile() {
    File directory = new File(GlobalVariables.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_ROOT);
    File[] allFiles = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : allFiles) {
       if (file.isDirectory() == false) {
        String filename = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf("."));
        File newDir = new File(filename);

        file.renameTo(new File(newDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getName()));
       }
    }
}
```

I got error message and there aren't any changes in file structure.

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   -1

I am looking for same functionality as `for /f %x in ('dir /ad /b') do move %x*.* %x\` Windows command.

Comment: Which line of code is producing the error? What filename is it operating on at the time?

Comment: Please go and Google that exception. It wants to tell you something that has nothing to do with the title of your question...

Comment: you have to master debugging

Comment: One of your files do not have `.` in file name therefore `file.getName().indexOf(".")` is returning -1 and ofcourse, -1 is `StringIndexOutOfBounds`

Comment: Kenster: that is really obvious. There is only one line here that uses indexOf(). Obviously not all names include a "." dot char.

Comment: Could you provide a sample before-after list?

Comment: @Prashant : All the filenames contain . , because all the files are pdf.

Comment: Then there are probably sub directories in the given directory

Comment: @Prashant : Yes, because folders and pdf files are in the same directory.

Comment: `listFIles()` list out both files and directories (Note that even directory is a file)

Comment: @Prashant : I added check for directories, it works without error message, but nothing happens with files.

Comment: Not sure what you you mean by "but nothing happens with files"

Comment: @Prashant : I logged out, so I am sure, code is executed, values of variables are correct, but there isn't any changes in file structure.